# outlook 2010 including weblink image inline

Tags: signature, outlook-2010

I have noticed on laptops once it has booted up and i open outlook to compose a message, the email signature picture takes a long time to load. 10seconds. during this time i believe outlook is download and trying to make a local copy within the email itsself. how can i prevent this from happening.

below is some code from a sent outlook email

```
<v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" alt="https://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg" style='position:absolute;margin-left:74.8pt;margin-top:0;width:126pt;height:34.5pt;z-index:251659264;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:0;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:0;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:right;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:line;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:page;mso-height-relative:page' o:allowoverlap="f">
<v:imagedata src="cid:image001.jpg@01D06CA4.6370D640" o:href="https://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg" />
<w:wrap type="square" anchory="line"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img width="168" height="46" src="cid:image001.jpg@01D06CA4.6370D640" align="right" alt="https://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_2"><![endif]><span style="font-size:12.0pt;color:#1F497D;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB">
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Outlook doesn't download external images automatically until the user clicks to download them manually.

Anyway, images referenced in the following manner are not external images:

```
src="cid:image001.jpg@01D06CA4.6370D640"
```

They are stored as hidden attachments. Try to use any low-level property viewer such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for observing the Attachments collection.

Comment: this means my theory is correct. outlook downloads the image and makes it avilable locally in the message, when creatin a new message?